# How to get data from jQuery script (web.py)?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, web.py

I can't find any tutorial for jQuery + web.py.
So I've got basic question on POST method.

I've got jQuery script:

```
<script>
     jQuery('#continue').click(function() {
         var command = jQuery('#continue').attr('value');
         jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: {signal : command},
         });
     });
</script>
```

A simple form:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" id="continue" value="next">Continue</button>
</form>
```

and python script:

```
def POST (self):
        s = signal
        print s
        return
```

I expect to see string "next" in console. But it doesn't happen.

I have a strong feeling that selectors somehow do not work. Any way to check it?

Comment: jQuery.ajax expects an url to post/get the content, so add the url param next to type and data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use web.input in web.py to access POST variables

look at the docs: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api (search for "function input")

```
def POST(self):
    s = web.input().signal
    print s
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     jQuery('#continue').click(function() {
         var command = jQuery('#continue').attr('value');
         jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: {signal : command},
              url: "add the url here"
         });
     });
</script>
```

**add the url of the server.**

Comment: found this example: http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/ - it works without URL.

Comment: As I understood from jQuery docs - current page is a default setting for URL, so I can ignore this line